# Using colon in `git pull origin <remote-branch> : <local-branch>` does not pull to correct branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-pull

Let's say I am on a *different*  branch than `<local-branch>`, called `<different-branch>`.

When I try to pull from a remote branch to a local branch, I do the following:

```
git pull origin <remote-branch>:<local-branch>
```

And, from my understanding this should  pull into my `<local-branch>`, and *not* pull into `<different-branch>`.

But, then when I check `git log` while I'm on `<different-branch>`, I see that those commits are from `<remote-branch>`?

How do I pull from a remote branch, into a local branch, when the local branch is different from the one that I cam currently on?    Thank you.

Comment: Did you include the spaces around the colon? Because those shouldn’t be there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `git pull` with a refspec will not affect the merging part of the pull command. As you maybe know, `git pull` is essentially just a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`; first, it will fetch the newest changes from the remote and update the remote-tracking branch, and then it will merge that remote-tracking branch into *the current branch*.

Now, as I said, the refspec does not affect the merging part, but it only affects the *fetching* inside `git pull`. Now to understand what this eventually means, you first have to understand what a refspec is.

A refspec is basically just a configuration which remote branches map to which remote-tracking branch. The remote branches are here the branches that actually exist on the remote, and the remote-tracking branches are the branches that are created to track the state of the remote branches; for a remote called “origin”, its remote-tracking branches all start with `origin/`.

If you don’t specify a refspec explicitely, it is taken from the configuration file. The default form usually looks like this:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This tells Git to fetch the remote branches located at `refs/heads/*` and map them to remote-tracking branches located at `refs/remotes/origin/*`. So for a remote branch `master`, `refs/heads/master` will map to `refs/remotes/origin/master`. The leading `+` also tells Git to overwrite the remote-tracking branch regardless of whether the changes could be fast-forwarded or not: After all, you usually want your remote-tracking branches to match *exactly* the state on the remote, so if the history is rewritten there (which should be avoided) or branches are renamed, you would want the remote-tracking branches to still respect that.

Now, when you specify the refspec (using `git fetch` or `git pull`), the default mapping is overridden. Instead, your mapping is used. For example, when you use `git fetch origin master:foo`, then a local branch `foo` is fast-forwarded (if possible) to point to the remote branch `master`. So this is actually a fine way to update a local branch, without having to check it out: If you leave out the leading `+`, then updating the local ref (branch) will fail if it’s not a fast-forward merge, so you’re also safe against conflicts.

But coming back to `git pull`—what happened when you ran the command? As I said, a pull is just a fetch and a merge, so your `git pull` command first did this:

```
git fetch origin <remote-branch>:<local-branch>
```

So the remote branch is fetched from the remote, and the local branch is updated—if it’s a fast-forward merge. This already does exactly what you wanted: Update `<local-branch>`.

But then, the merge part of `git pull` happens; and Git usually runs `git merge FETCH_HEAD` for this purpose. `FETCH_HEAD` is a reference to the last fetched branches. In this case, it points at `<local-branch>`. So after fetching into `<local-branch>`, the command that is being executed is `git merge <local-branch>`. And running `git merge` will merge into *the current branch*.

So when you’re on `<different-branch>` and run `git pull origin <remote-branch>:<local-branch>` then you will correctly update `<local-branch>` to match the remote branch, but you will then also merge those changes into the current branch, `<different-branch>`. That’s why you see the changes of that branch in the log of the current branch; they were simply merged.

If you want to avoid that, as per my explanations above, just use `git fetch` with the refspec. It will already update the local branch correctly (if it can) without affecting the current branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  when you say "In this case, it points at <local-branch>. So after fetching into <local-branch>, the command that is being executed is git merge <local-branch>. And running git merge will merge into the current branch."  ....What is `<local branch>` here?  Are you merging the remote-tracking branch with the locally-held branch?  If so, how can you do that using a refspec?

Comment: I suppose part of my confusion is...When to use a colon and when to just use a space?    e.g. `git fetch origin <remote-branch>:<local-branch>` versus `git merge origin <remote-branch> <local-branch>`?

Comment: Usually, unless you explicitly want to fetch into a different local tracking branch, you should never use a refspec manually. If you ever come into a situation where the default refspec is not okay, you should adjust the config. So you probably never need the refspec with `fetch`. And with `pull`, just don’t use it ever as it doesn’t do what you would expect.

Comment: the problem is that the refspec seems to assume that your local and remote branches will always be the same name.  If someone changes one of the branch names remotely, but you want to keep your local name, then you would need to use a refspec manually, like: `git fetch origin <remote name>:<local name>`, `git checkout <local name>`, `git merge remotes/origin/<local name>`.  is that right?

Comment: Usually, you would only use `git fetch` without a refspec, this already fetches all remote branches. And in case a branch is renamed on the remote (which is somewhat rare), you could just update your local branch to track that new one instead: `git branch -u origin/new_remote`. This will update the current branch to track `new_remote` on the remote instead. So then you can use `git push` and `git pull` for that branch without any refspec.

Answer (score 2):

You can always go low tech:

```
git fetch origin #fetches all the remote branches
git checkout <local-branch>
git merge origin/<remote-branch>
```

or if you practice rebase pulls

```
git rebase -i origin/<remote-branch> <local-branch>
```

Comment: I assume you mean `remotes/origin/<remote-branch>` instead of `origin/<remote-branch>`, right?

Comment: @Candic3 whatever works for you. Normally ‘origin‘ would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track the remote branch as well you can use the following:

`git checkout --track -b local-branch origin/remote-branch`

You might need to run `git fetch` first if the remote branch was created after you last fetched.