# Why can’t I use git pull with a local branch?

Tags: git

I am new to git. What is the difference between specifying a local branch and not?

```
$ git pull origin master : local-branch
 ! [rejected]   master  -> local-branch  (non-fast-forward)

$ git pull origin master
 * branch      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: The exact spelling of commands is very important: `git pull origin master<space><colon><space>local-branch` and `git pull origin master:local-branch`, without spaces, do different things. It looks to me like you ran `git pull origin master:local-branch`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: which branch u r in when running the command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147716/using-colon-in-git-pull-origin-remote-branch-local-branch-does-not-pull

Comment: when you not specify name of your local branch merge happened to branch, which currently checkout

Comment: @torek also get the same result;                                                                  
git pull origin master:test-none-fastword-problem 
From https://github.com/....
 ! [rejected]        master     -> test-none-fastword-problem  (non-fast-forward)

Comment: Yes, without the spaces, that might be expected (depending on what you have in your branch name-space).

Answer (score 0):

The branches have diverged at some point. There must be commits that exist on `local-branch` that do not exist on `master`, and as such, you might have to rewrite local history, and rebase local changes on top of the remote branch.

Comment: i have commit all on local-branch,what is the difference between git pull origin origin-branch:local-branch and git pull origin origin-branch.why the first one cont not work ,but the second one can work.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you're passing an inappropriate refspec to `git fetch`.  Because `git fetch` is pretty safe, it's detecting this and making the whole thing fail.

#### `git pull` = `git fetch` plus a second Git command

I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely (at least as a beginner).  It does too many things at once.

What `git pull` does is to run two Git commands.

The first command it runs is `git fetch`.  This command, when used in the normal way as a normal user command, is pretty safe.  You just run `git fetch` with no arguments at all, or `git fetch origin` if you want to specify that the fetch goes to `origin`.  (The default is normally to go to `origin` anyway.)

Running `git fetch origin` just obtains new commits from another Git, for which your Git has you use this short-hand name `origin`.  The short-hand name takes the place of a longer URL like `git://github.com/someuser/long/path/to/repository`.  This *remote*, as your Git calls it, refers to another Git repository.  That other Git repository has its *own* branches, and is manipulated by some other person or people, so that its branches acquire new commits over time.  This `git fetch` step has your Git call up that other Git over the Internet-phone and download the new commits.  Your Git then remembers them using what Git calls *remote-tracking branch names*, like `origin/master`.

In other words, your Git calls up their Git and asks: *Hey, what branches do you have?*  They may say: *I have `master` and its tip commit is `a234567...`*.  Your Git checks in your repository and finds that you do, or don't, have `a234567...`.  If you *don't*, your Git has their Git send you that commit, and everything needed to make that commit complete: all of its files and history.  If you already have that commit, this step goes very fast since there is nothing needed.  Then your Git says: *OK, now that I know `origin`'s master is `a234567...` I'll record that as `origin/master = a234567...`*.

That's *why* this step is so safe: your Git calls up some other Git, such as the one at `origin`.  Your Git obtains any commits (and other data) they have that you don't, and adds it to your repository, without touching any of *your* commits or branches at all.  If the other Git has *removed* some commits—which is a little difficult, but is possible—your Git updates your memory of what's in that other Git, with their branches maybe even having been shortened ... but this still doesn't touch any of *your* commits and branches *at all*, not in any way!

#### At this point things get more complicated (and less safe)

There is a reason `git pull` runs a second Git command.  If all it did was what this kind of default `git fetch` does, *your* branches would never acquire any of the new commits your Git picked up from their Git.

If you are doing your own work, and have made your own commits, it *may* now be time to *combine* your work with their work.  To combine your work with theirs, you must now run a second Git command.

The correct command to run *may* be `git merge`.  Or, it *may* be `git rebase`.  Or you may wish not to do either one at all yet: it's often a good idea to look at what just came in with `git fetch`, and decide between merge and rebase—or even some other option—based on that.  But the `git pull` command requires that you decide *in advance*, before seeing what comes in.

By default, `git pull` will run `git merge` as its second step, and if that's what you want—and you somehow know this in advance—you *can* use `git pull` to run both `git fetch` *and* `git merge`.  But I recommend doing them separately anyway: it will make things clearer to you, especially when something goes wrong.  You will know *which* command failed, and that's extremely helpful when you go searching StackOverflow for what to do about that failure.

#### It's actually the fetch part that fails here

In any case, the part that's failing in your example:

> ```
> ! [rejected]   master  -> local-branch  (non-fast-forward)
> ```

is actually the `git fetch` step, not the `git merge` step.  This is because of the syntax you used, and the way `git pull` invokes `git fetch`:

```
git pull origin master:local-branch
```

(note that there are no spaces around the colon).

The way `git pull` invokes `git fetch` is to pass most of these arguments through unchanged.  In particular, this `git pull` runs:

```
git fetch origin master:local-branch
```

as its `git fetch` step.<sup>1</sup>  The `origin` part is still just the name of your remote—short-hand for some URL, and useful in making up your-side names like `origin/master` to remember their branch names—but the rest of the parameters are what [the `git fetch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) calls a *refspec*.

Depending on what is in these refspecs and what your Git gets from the other Git, this first step—the `git fetch` part of a `git pull`—can fail.  If it *succeeds*, Git goes on to run the second step, which defaults to `git merge`.  The arguments passed to this `git merge` are a bit tricky, but it's important to remember that `git merge` always works within your *current branch*, whatever branch that is.

Beware: if you run `git pull origin a b c`, this runs `git fetch origin a b c` (which is not really a problem) followed by `git merge <hash1> <hash2> <hash3>`.  This second command performs what Git calls an *octopus merge*, and it is definitely not what you want, if you are a beginner.  This means that `git pull` is very easy to use incorrectly!  In particular, it's tempting to think that this would bring several of your own branches up to date.  But it won't—it *can't*—because it always works with your current branch, and you only get one current branch at a time.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, it also secretly passes `--update-head-ok`, or did back when it was a script; but you should never do this yourself.

---

#### References and refspecs

In Git, a *reference* is mostly a full-name variety of a branch name, or tag name, or remote-tracking branch name, and so on.  That is, the name `master` is short for `refs/heads/master`, which is the full *reference name* for branch `master`.  You can leave reference names shortened; if you do, the rules for figuring out the full name are spelled out in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  See the link for details, and note that turning a short name into a branch reference is actually way down at step four: three other steps could resolve it first, if any of those three work out.

A *refspec* is mostly just a pair of references, with a colon in between them (and no spaces).  The name on the left is a *source* and the name on the right is a *destination*, so `master:master` means that the source name is `master` and the destination name is `master`, while `master:local-branch` means that the source name is `master` and the destination name is `local-branch`.  As usual with references, Git will try to figure out the correct full name if you give a short name.

For `git fetch`, the *source* is the name on the other Git (which is the source of any new commits), and the *destination* should generally be a remote-tracking branch name: an appropriate pair, for instance would be:

```
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

(this `refs/remotes/` is the prefix for all of your remote-tracking branch names).<sup>2</sup>  But that's not what you're running.  Instead, you are giving your Git:

```
master:local-branch
```

which your Git expands out to:

```
refs/heads/master:refs/heads/local-branch
```

Your Git calls up their Git as usual, obtains any commits they have on their `master` that you don't have in your repository, and then tries to *safely* adjust your `refs/heads/local-branch` reference to match their current setting of their `master`.  It's not safe—doing this is not a "fast forward"—so your Git stops with an error.

---

<sup>2</sup>For `git push`, these are reversed: `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/jackiewillen` would ask them to set *their* branch named `jackiewillen` to point to the same commit as *your* branch named `master`.  Note that here, there is no notion of a remote-tracking name: when you push to the other Git you just ask them to set their branches directly, rather than taking their names and constructing `origin/whatever` from them.

---

#### A fast-forward is simple in graph terms

To understand what a "fast-forward" is and why it's "safe"—and a "non fast forward" is correspondingly *un*safe—you need to learn how Git's references work with Git's commit graph.  This answer is way too long already, though, so I'll defer a lot of this to the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Fundamentally, though, as the above site points out, references make commits *reachable*.  This means that changing the value of some reference—changing the specific commit identified by a branch name, in this case—changes the set of reachable commits.  If the *new* branch tip is a descendant of the old branch tip—is a child, or grandchild, or great-great-great-grandkid, for instance—then all the old commits will still be reachable.  The old branch tip is a parent, or grandparent, or great-great-...-grandparent, of the child, so moving a branch name in this fashion is what Git calls a *fast-forward* operation.

(Git spells out this "fast-forward" idea directly with the `git merge` command, which is a slightly odd thing to do, because a fast-forward operation is *not* actually a merge at all.  If `git merge` *can* do a fast-forward, you must tell it not to, using `--no-ff`, to force Git to make a new merge commit.  Even then, the new merge *commit*, which is a merge-as-an-adjective, requires no merging-action-as-a-verb work.  Only when merge-as-a-verb is required does `git merge` default to making a merge-as-an-adjective commit.  But that's a `git merge` thing: it uses the same reachability concepts, but in a different way.)

Anyway, that is in fact the rule: a branch-name change is a fast-forward operation if the *current value* of the branch-name is an ancestor of the *new, proposed value* for the branch-name.  Otherwise, it's not a fast-forward.

In both `git fetch` *and* `git push`, a fast-forward operation like this is normally allowed.  Such an operation is safe: once the branch name value is changed, the new value accommodates all the old commits *plus* the new commits.  No commits have been taken away; new commits are added.  Contrariwise, a non-fast-forward operation is normally forbidden.  Such an operation is *not* safe: once the branch name value is changed, some existing commits are no longer reachable, at least not from the changed branch name.  If they're not reachable from some other name, those commits are *forgotten*, and become eligible for garbage collection.  These commits are eventually removed.

To force a branch-name value change even if it's not a fast-forward, Git allows you to specify a "force flag".  Both `git fetch` and `git push` support `--force`, which sets the force flag on all the updates that this one `git fetch` or `git push` command proposes.  But there's a way to write this directly within a refspec: a leading plus sign, `+`, sets the force flag.

Hence, even if it's not a fast-forward operation, the command:

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

will change your `origin/master` remote-tracking branch name—the destination reference—to match the other Git's `master` branch.  And this is why the default refspec for `git fetch origin` is normally:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The two asterisks mean "match anything" and "use whatever got matched".  So by default, just running `git fetch origin` will obtain whatever they have and update your `origin/whatever`s.

#### But what about the one that works?

There's one oddity that does not fit here:

> ```
> * branch      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

The `* branch` part means that the name refers to a branch.  But `FETCH_HEAD` is not a branch name, and this `git fetch` step works every time.  What's up with that?

The secret is that remotes, like `origin`, and remote-tracking branch names like `origin/master`, were a late invention.  Git did not have them at all, at first.  In fact, Git did not have a user-oriented `git fetch` either; it had only `git pull`.  This is why the opposite of `git push` is `git fetch`: having only `git pull` was a mistake.  Git should have had `git pull` do what `git fetch` does.  (Mercurial's `hg pull` does what Git's `git fetch` does,<sup>3</sup> so Mercurial's pull and push are in fact paired up, while Git's just aren't.)

Anyway, as a side effect:

1. `git fetch origin refs/heads/master`, which has a refspec with a source but no destination, essentially means *fetch their `master` and then throw it away.*  Just before throwing it away, though, Git will now<sup>4</sup> update `origin/master` first.
2. *Everything* that `git fetch` fetches, `git fetch` dumps into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This file has contents that are deliberately similar to references that are resolved in step 1 of the seven steps listed in [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  They are not exactly the same, though: they get augmented with additional data, left behind specifically for `git pull` to use.

The contents of this special `FETCH_HEAD` file last only until the *next* `git fetch`, which overwrites it.  (The `--append` option to `git fetch` tells `git fetch` to append to `FETCH_HEAD` rather than overwriting it, but this rarely useful.)  That's good enough for `git pull`, since `git pull` first runs `git fetch`—which drops this key information into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`—and then, as long as the `fetch` step succeeded, immediately runs either `git merge` or `git rebase` using data that the pull code reads from `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, where the `git fetch` step left it.

If you avoid `git pull`, this special song and dance routine that `git fetch` performs using `.git/FETCH_HEAD` becomes irrelevant: you don't need to know that it happens, and you can ignore the contents of `FETCH_HEAD`.  If you do use `git pull` *and it works*, you don't need to know this either.  You only need to know this for cases where `git pull` fails for some reason.

---

<sup>3</sup>At one point, possibly just to be confusing, :-) Mercurial had an extension named `fetch` that ran `hg pull` followed by `hg merge`.  This meant that `hg pull` = `git fetch`, and `hg fetch` = `git pull`!

<sup>4</sup>As of Git 1.8.4, where opportunistic updating during `git fetch` was added.