# why "git push git push origin local-branch :development" will delete remote development branch?

Tags: git

why "git push git push origin local-branch :development" will delete remote development branch?

```
jackiewillen  ~/Documents/work/  git push origin yrh-deskmonitor-20170905 :development
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/id_rsa':
To ssh://git.dianpingoa.com/ed-f2e/gandalf-plus.git
 - [deleted]         development
```

i try "push origin local-branch:development" is ok!So problem is on the semicolon;with space before semicolon or not is different.Why?

Comment: This is why I said in https://stackoverflow.com/q/46090029/1256452 that the *exact spelling* is crucial. Spaces in particular separate "words" in command line interpreters, and the command that is run will often look at each word in isolation. (Every command has its own quirks though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the space between `yrh-deskmonitor-20170905 :development`

You've pushed `yrh-deskmonitor-20170905` as is AND deleted `development` branch

Probably, you wished to run

```
git push origin yrh-deskmonitor-20170905:development
```

instead.

The syntax of `git push` is like this:

```
git push <target> <refspec1> <refspec2> <refspec3>
```

where all `<refspec>s` are independent from each other and each may be in the following forms:

1. `<branch-or-tag-name>`
2. `<local-refname>:<remote-branch-name>`
3. `:<branch-or-tag-name>`
4. various "hacks" when remote refs is specified with name starting with `refs/...`.

   - case 1 is used to create branches in a remote repo directly corresponding to branches in the local repo. This is the most "natural" usage.
   - case 2 is for creating a branch in a remote repo with a name different from the local one (I suppose, your case)
   - case 3 is for deleting given branches in the remote repo.
   - case 4 allows to create unsigned tags, different remotes and other kind of hacks that can be described as "low-level".

Don't worry, you still can re-create `development` branch (almost) without a harm by issuing `git push <target> yrh-deskmonitor-20170905:development`

Comment: is there is a document about this different?i search that on the pro git.but can not find!

Comment: See the @SamvelPetrosov answer. Actually one may push several refs at once, separating them by a space. Also one may delete a ref existing in a remote repo by issuing push with `:<something>` argument. That's exactly your case

Comment: In turn, The form `git push <target> <ref>:<remote-ref-name>` allows to save a remote reference with a name, different from the local one

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-codegitpushoriginexperimentalcode) of the git push:

> git push origin :experimental
>   Find a ref that matches experimental in
>   the origin repository (e.g. refs/heads/experimental), and delete it.

Comment: does the "git push origin branch :development" is equal to "git push origin branch branch:branch" +"git push origin :development"?how do you know this.

Comment: Jackie, do you not see what you did?  `git push origin branch:otherbranch` with _no space_ says to push the local `branch` to the remote `otherbranch`.  But `git push origin branch :otherbranch` _with a space_ says to do _two_ things.  First, push local `branch` to the remote `branch` with the same name, and second, _delete_ the remote `otherbranch`.

Comment: Check also in the documentation of `git push` the section about `refspec`, which can be `<src>:<dest>`, and where "pushing an empty <src> allows you to delete the <dst> ref from the remote repository."